# When reading a file trying to determine valid grades, why does the file reader skip lines?

Tags: java, file, filereader

When i run this, the reader only reads and displays every other line. What am i doing wrong?

```
while (imputFile.hasNext()) {
            grade = imputFile.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(grade);
            if (grade < 0 || grade > 100)
                System.out.print("Grade " + grade + " was invalid and ignored");
            else {
                numberOfGrades++;
                sum += imputFile.nextDouble();
            }
        }
    averageGrade = sum/numberOfGrades;
    System.out.println("There were "+ numberOfGrades + " valid grades.");
    System.out.printf("%3.2f",averageGrade);
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with your problem, but can you please change every instance of `imputFile` in your code to `inputFile`?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `imputFile.nextDouble()` in your loop twice:

```
grade = imputFile.nextDouble();
//....
sum += imputFile.nextDouble();
```

Try changing last line to

```
sum += grade;
```

to use already read value, not to read next one.

Comment: For clarity, he's talking about the line in your `else` block.